# Struggling to copy between workbooks

Tags: excel, vba, copy-paste

I've got to copy one cell at a time to rearrange the columns from a specific row based on a value in that row. This code worked perfectly copying from one sheet to another sheet within one workbook. Now I have tried to expand it to copy between workbooks. I cannot for the life of me get it to work. Any help would be appreciated. Ps) Some code removed to simplify

```
    Dim bomWB As Workbook
    Set bomWB = ThisWorkbook
    
    strFullname = ("C:\Users\AlexA\Desktop\") & PartNo
    Workbooks.Add.SaveAs Filename:=strFullname ', FileFormat:=xlcsv
    Dim NewWB As Workbook
    Set NewWB = ThisWorkbook

bomWB.Activate
Dim xRg As Range
Dim xCell As Range
Dim I As Long
Dim R As Long
Dim L As Long

I = Worksheets("Main BOM").UsedRange.Rows.Count
Set xRg = Worksheets("Main BOM").Range("H2:H" & I)

On Error Resume Next
'Application.ScreenUpdating = False

For L = 1 To xRg.Count
    If CStr(xRg(L).Value) = "0" Then GoTo Skip
            R = R + 1
    
    Workbooks(bomWB).Worksheets("Main BOM").Range("H" & L + 1).Copy _
                Destination:=Workbooks(NewWB).Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & R + 1)
Skip:

Next
```

Comment: Are you getting any errors?

Comment: What is the intention behind the line `Workbooks.Add.SaveAs`? Also, `Set bomWB = ThisWorkbook` And `Set NewWB = ThisWorkbook` are both targetting the same workbook. `ThisWorkbook` refers to the book containing the code module and will not change during execution. You might have intended to use `ActiveWorkbook` which would have changed when you created a new workbook during your line `Workbooks.Add.SaveAs`.

Comment: Also,  `Workbooks(bomWB).Worksheets` should be just `bomWB.Worksheets`. No need to use `Workbooks()` on a workbook object

Comment: @EylM - nope it runs through!

Comment: @Toddleson Workbooks.Add.SaveAs is to create a new file to extract the data to. Thanks for the headsup about Thisworkbook and ActiveWorkbook. I've removed the workbooks prefix as well. Finally it's working. The only problem is that I'm having to do a SaveAs csv at the end which is creating two workbooks so I need to find a way to avoid ending up with two workbooks. Thanks for all of your help.

Comment: In the final iteration, I removed the initial SaveAs from the Workbooks.Add and the performed the SaveAs .csv right at the end. I couldn't have got this done without your help, I owe you an internet beer or three :-)

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim bomWB As Workbook
Set bomWB = ThisWorkbook
    
strFullname = ("C:\Users\AlexA\Desktop\") & PartNo
Workbooks.Add
Dim NewWB As Workbook
Set NewWB = ActiveWorkbook

bomWB.Activate
Dim xRg As Range
Dim xCell As Range
Dim I As Long
Dim R As Long
Dim L As Long

I = Worksheets("Main BOM").UsedRange.Rows.Count
Set xRg = Worksheets("Main BOM").Range("H2:H" & I)

On Error Resume Next
'Application.ScreenUpdating = False

For L = 1 To xRg.Count
If CStr(xRg(L).Value) = "0" Then GoTo Skip
            R = R + 1
    
bomWB.Worksheets("Main BOM").Range("H" & L + 1).Copy _
                Destination:=NewWB.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & R + 1)
Skip:

Next

NewWB.SaveAs Filename:=strFullname, FileFormat:=xlCSV
NewWB.Close
```